# Methods vs separate classes for widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I heard a lot about "flutter method-widgets is considered anti-pattern". But why? Elements don't care about widgets' parameters (equal or not). Only const widgets save rebuilds. So why do I have to separate them to relatively verbose classes, when I could just

```
Widget _buildMe() => Container() // here is some widget, which depends on other params (so it cannot be const)
```

inside my StatelessWidget class.

Update: I also assume that methods don't depend on InheritedWidget. In that case it's obvious, that they should be separated.

Comment: Have you read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58951384/10746978) answer?

Comment: It's not what I asked. "Having no context" (read no element) is different form "sharing context/element". Furthermore, element is created for each widget you use anyway. Also, imho, when card title shares same context as card - it's ok. So I don't understand why I should define separate widget for that. It doesn't prevent rebuilds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an anti-pattern, because in some cases it leads to unnecessary rebuilds (depending on Inherited widget for example). But in general you can use it, if you use it wisely (2-3 methods in class don't make any harm).